# Segmentation fault: 11 Server/Client

Tags: c, sockets, if-statement, client-server

```
enum recstate {
    initial
};

int num_clients = 0;

static void addclient(int fd, struct in_addr addr){
    struct client *p = (struct client *) malloc (sizeof(struct client));
    if (!p) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Adding client %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
    p->fd = fd;           
    p->next = top;        
    p->state = initial;   
    top = p;             
    num_clients++;
}

struct client {
    int fd;               // socket descriptor for this client
    enum recstate state;  // current state of data transfer for this client
    struct client *next;  // a pointer to the next client in the list
    struct in_addr ipaddr;
} *top = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int listenfd, clientfd, maxfd, nready;
    struct client *p;
    struct sockaddr_in self, client;

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&self, '\0', sizeof(self));
    self.sin_family      = AF_INET; 
    self.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    self.sin_port        = htons(PORT); 

    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &self, sizeof(self))){
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(listenfd, 5) < 0){
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (1){
        fd_set allset, rset;
        FD_ZERO(&allset);           
        FD_SET(listenfd, &allset);  
        maxfd = listenfd;           

        rset = allset;

        for (p = top; p; p = p->next){
            FD_SET(p->fd, &allset); 
            if (p->fd > maxfd){
                maxfd = p->fd;      
            }
        }

        if(FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)){ 
            printf("Listenfd is ready\n");
            len = sizeof(client);

            if ((clientfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &len)) < 0){
                perror("accept");
                return(1);
            }

            else {
                printf("Connection from %s\n", inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
                addclient(clientfd, client.sin_addr);

                FD_SET(clientfd, &rset);
                printf("clientfd has been added to fdset\n");

                if(p->state == initial){ //cannot get into this if statement
                    printf("now in initial state\n");

                    nready = select(maxfd + 1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

                    if(nready == 0){
                        printf("timeout happened\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if(nready == -1){
                        perror("select");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (nready > 0){
                        printf("Data is now available.\n");
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)){ //returns a value for fd in rset
                        //read data into file
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of my server code. 
I'm trying to send files from the client to the server, but when I send the files from the client, the server will execute until just above the if(p->state == initial) statement, and hangs there. When I terminate the server, it'll give me a segmentation fault: 11 error.
Also, I'm using select() inside the initial state to allow multiple clients to connect simultaneously.
Don't know where I went wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like p is NULL at the point of that if statement?  If so (or if p is set to some other invalid value) that would probably explain the misbehavior.  You might put a printf("p=%p\n", p) just before the if and see what the value is just before you dereference it.

Comment: Okay, so I just ran it and apparently, p=0x0

Comment: So how would I set p != NULL?

Comment: Set it like any other variable `p = __THE_VALUE_YOU_NEED_IN_P__;` .

Answer (score 0):

`for (p = top; p; p = p->next){`

Unless I'm mistaken, you loop until `p` is `NULL`

`if(p->state == initial){`

and then you dereference `p`.
**KABOOM**.